# SQL Server: create unique key across multiple rows for continuous dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a set of data for users starting and stopping a program. I need to determine total time running for each instance.  However, if the program is stopped and started on the same day I need it to be continuous.

End result should be:

```
User    Start      End        EventId
--------------------------------------
X       1/1/2016   1/1/2016   1
X       1/1/2016   1/5/2016   1
X       1/5/2016   1/10/2016  1
X       1/10/2016  1/13/2016  1
X       12/20/2016 12/26/2016 2
Y       01/01/2016 01/01/2016 3
Y       01/01/2016 01/02/2016 3
Y       01/04/2016 01/10/2016 4
```

or:

```
User   EventId   DurationDays
------------------------------
  X       1         13
  Y       2          6
  Y       3          2
  Y       4          6
```

But I figured if someone can help me get to grouping them properly I can take care of that easily enough.

Table below is how far I've gotten my results:

```
User    Start   End         LagStart      LagStop
-------------------------------------------------
X   1/1/2016    1/1/2016    Startgroup  
X   1/1/2016    1/5/2016    Follow  
X   1/5/2016    1/10/2016   Follow  
X   1/10/2016   1/13/2016   Follow        StopGroup
X   12/20/2016  12/26/2016  StartGroup    StopGroup
X   12/26/2016  12/30/2016  Startgroup    StopGroup
Y   01/01/2016  01/01/2016  StartGroup    
Y   01/01/2016  01/02/2016  StartGroup    StopGroup
Y   01/04/2016  01/10/2016  StartGroup    StopGroup
```

I'm stumped on creating new unique ids starting at each "Startgroup" and ending at each "Stopgroup"

If it helps to see the buildup to this set of data please see below:

```
select
    a.user_start_key as firstStartKey, 
    a.user_end_key as firstEndKey, 
    a.start_dt as firstStartDate,
    a.end_dt as firstDisch, 
    a.rnkkey as firstRank,
    nextRec.user_start_key as nextStart,
    nextRec.start_dt,
    nextRec.max_rank,
    case 
       when Lag(nextRec.max_rank, 1) over (order by a.rnkkey) is null 
          then 'StartGroup'
       when Lag(nextRec.max_rank, 1) over (order by a.rnkkey) in (a.rnkkey)  
          then 'Follow' 
       else 'Start' 
    end as LagStart,
    case 
       when lead(a.rnkkey, 1) over (order by a.rnkkey) is null 
          then 'StopGroup' 
       when lead(a.rnkkey, 1) over (order by a.rnkkey) <> nextRec.max_rank 
          then 'StopGroup' 
       else Null 
    end as Lagstop
from 
    #rnk1 a
inner join 
    (Select Distinct 
         user_start_key, 
         start_dt,
         --dschrg_dt,
         max(rnkkey) over (partition by user_start_key order by end_dt desc) max_rank
     from 
         #rnk1) nextRec on a.user_end_key = nextRec.user_start_key
```

The "User_[state]_key" field is just me building a unique key by date for each user_id since there are multiple users and I need them to be grouped separately.

If I need to clarify any further please let me know.  Thanks for anyone who can help.

Comment: You have some records in your desired output where user is Y but your table doesn't have any users with the value Y?

Comment: Apologies, entry error on my part.  Assume there can be any number of users.  I've updated the sample result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that uses a cummulative sum to calculate a ranking.
So that the ranking can be used to group on.

```
-- Using a table variable for easy testing
declare @T table (id int identity(1,1) primary key, [User] varchar(8), startdate date, enddate date);
-- Sample data
insert into @T ([User], startdate, enddate) values
 ('X','2018-01-01','2018-01-01')
,('X','2018-01-01','2018-01-05')
,('X','2018-01-05','2018-01-10')
,('X','2018-01-10','2018-01-13')
,('X','2018-12-20','2018-12-26')
,('Y','2018-01-01','2018-01-01')
,('Y','2018-01-01','2018-01-02')
,('Y','2018-01-04','2018-01-10')
;

select 
 [User], 
 cumm_sum_rank as EventId, 
 datediff(day, min(startdate), max(enddate))+1 as DurationDays
 , min(startdate) as [Start]
 , max(enddate) as [End]
from
(
    select *, 
     sum(startdate_diff_prev_enddate) over (order by [User], startdate, enddate) as cumm_sum_rank
    from
    (
        select [User], startdate, enddate, 
         iif(startdate = lag(enddate) over (partition by [User] order by startdate, enddate),0,1) as startdate_diff_prev_enddate
        from @T
    ) as q1
) as q2
group by [User], cumm_sum_rank;
```